# How to load an image resource from a URL into a PHP script, using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, php-gd

I'm using the Google Charts service to generate some QR codes that I afterward need to manipulate (e.g. rotate, scale) in a PHP script and merge with other images to generate one final image.

How do I correctly load such a resource (from a URL) into a PHP script, in a way that will allow me to manipulate it?

An example URL is: [https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=xghsdfgsdfg&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=xghsdfgsdfg&choe=UTF-8&chld=L%7C0)

I currently have the following code to retrieve the image using cURL:

```
function getImage($url){
        $ch = curl_init ($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $resource = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        return $resource;
}
```

But when I use it like this:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng(getImage("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=xghsdfgsdfg&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0"));
```

The following error is returned:

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(‰PNG  ) [function.imagecreatefrompng]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/picselbc/public_html/projects/cakemyface/preview.php on line 383
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=xghsdfgsdfg&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need instead of `imagecreatefrompng()` is [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php), because the former expects a filename instead of the file contents itself.

Comment: You're right, that works! Any idea what I can do if I use the SimpleImage class though? ([link](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/the-simple-image-class-for-php/)). Because I'd need to use it like so: `$image = new SimpleImage(getImage($url));`.

Comment: If `SimpleImage` needs a file you have to write one in a temporary location perhaps?

Comment: I was afraid you would say that :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=xghsdfgsdfg&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0'));
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

Note: I had to use http rather than https because I haven't set up ssl on my local server.